# My question is about IF function in WHILE

Tags: python

I would like to ask you why while if loop doesn't work for me, I think the problem is with conditions but I tried to find out where it can be and I couldn't.

```
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as keyboardController

mouse = Controller ()
keyboard = keyboardController ()
var = 0
a = 0
b = 3
c = 1

time.sleep(5)
while var == 0:
    if a < b:
        mouse.position = (1199, 924)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(3)
        keyboard.press('n')
        keyboard.release('n')
        time.sleep(0.7)
        keyboard.press('\b')
        keyboard.release('\b')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        a + c
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        mouse.position = (48, 445)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (819, 425)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(1)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for char in "De Gea":
            keyboard.press(char)
            keyboard.release(char)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        time.sleep(1)
        mouse.position = (733, 533)
        ntime.sleep(1)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (1109, 851)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for char2 in "50000":
            keyboard.press(char2)
            keyboard.release(char2)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        mouse.position = (1187, 937)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        b = 0
```

I tried many different solutions, instead of a,b,c put there numbers and other things but still doesnt work.
Thanks for any hints and sorry I am just beginner.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Be more specific.

Comment: Separately program works fine, in IF and in ELSE, but after 4rd repeat it doesn't switch

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: Basicly this is 2 sections, 1st is in IF and 2nd is in ELSE, i would like to repeat "program" in IF function 150 times, and after it i need to do comands after ELSE and again with 150 times if..

Comment: `var` never changes, so `while var == 0` is an infinite loop.  Is this intended?  Also, `a + c` does not alter the value of a.  It adds a and c together, but it does not assign that result anywhere, so this statement effectively does nothing.  Perhaps you meant `a = a + c`?

Comment: yes, var needs to be an infinite loop, and I need to increase a by 1 every time code is made

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `else` branch is never taken, because `a` and `b` never change. You have the line

```
a + c
```

but what you need to understand is *this doesn't do anything*. At the start of the program, `a + c == 0 + 1 == 1`. What does this do for you? Nothing, because that `1` isn't going anywhere. If you want `a` to change (and thus for the `else` block to eventually be taken when `a < b` is no longer true), you have to *assign* the result of that to a:

```
a = a + c
```

Alternatively, you could use the operator `+=`:

```
a += c
```

---

Also, you're never changing the value of `var`, so your loop will never end, but I'm assuming that's intentional for the time being

Comment: Yes, that was the answer, sorry guys, as I said I am just beginner and I think in C+ it worked like this. Thanks for your responses.